# Apps Script Webapp not reporting to Google Analytics - works on firefox and works on localhost

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-analytics, chromium

I created a general public webapp that is published for anyone even anonymous. I included code for gtag.js and google tag manager and have an analytics enabled account.

Trying to verify everything works, I couldnt see any realtime active users on the analytics dashboard. I then entered the same webapp with Firefox and the active user appeared.

I did a last test of dumping the whole webapp as static html page served on my localhost and it works as expected both in Firefox and Chrome/Chromium.

So I guess something combining chrome + apps script iframes/postMessage/whatever boilerplate is messed up for Chrome family browsers.

I tried using the Chrome Extension Tag Assistant and confirm that there are events fired when on localhost but nothing when running from https://script.google.com/a/macros/... thing.

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this ?

ps: I am not interested in building an app for server-side built reports with the AnalyticsApps, but just to record the activity of users on my webapp.
ps2: Adblock is disabled

edit: here is a quick example that you may test on this url:
Check here:https://script.google.com/a/macros/safewebmed.com.br/s/AKfycbwGoFhpo5qekznUEn9z4Crt9BtFz0ubDsjK9sNlcJz0xTroscdU/exec?testga=true

**index.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
    if (e.parameter.testga) {
        var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('src/html/testga');
        var html = template.evaluate().setTitle('testga').setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
        return html;               
    }
}
```

**testga.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-PM7KHPS');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-179509330-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-179509330-1');
</script>    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This reports correctly realtime user online with Firefox, but not with Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: post code of your file pls

Comment: edited with example

Comment: Hi ! What Chrome version are you using ? If you are not using the latest one, could you update it and check again to see if that was the main issue ? Thanks ! :D

Comment: I am using Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Linux Mint !

Comment: Could you try updating it to the latest version just in case? [Here](https://www.google.com/chrome/update/) are some instructions on updating Chrome. Let me know how that goes :D

Answer (score 0):

**It works for me on Chrome**, try to *refresh* the page with cache cleaning or check if you have not enabled the `Same site` settings in browser setting.

Comment: you mean you created a GAS webapp, changed to your ID's, opened it with chrome and saw a visitor on Analytics ???

Comment: I opened your URL and saw the call to Analytics in the console of the browser (Chrome).